# jquery select anchors whose custom attr is not undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, attr

```
<a myattr="something">anchor</a>
<a>anchor</a>

$(a[myattr]) does not work
$(a[myattr!="") does not work
$(a[myattr!==undefined) does not work
```

What works for getting those anchors whose "myattr" are defined and equal to something?

Comment: If you put the selectors between quotes, your first one should work. http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/nuUrt/

Comment: @FabrícioMatté You should post that as an answer..

Comment: Note that, as far as I remember, void attribute selectors don't work in IE7- (maybe even buggy in IE8 in special combinations)

Comment: $(a[myattr])  should be like $('a[myattr]')  .. Missing the quotes for the selector expression..

Comment: I thought OP could have a more complex problem and just typo'd it, I'm pretty sure the attribute selectors should work even in older IEs as jQuery utilizes Sizzle.

Comment: OP, if none of the answers can solve the issue, feel free to update your question. Usually, if you're doing event binding and adding content dynamically, you'll need [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). Apart from dynamically added content, the quotes should solve your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you put the selector between quotes, your first one should work.

```
$('a[myattr]')
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/nuUrt)

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/Be9Ab/

```
$("a[myattr]").css("color","red");​
```

Works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery("a").each(function(){
            if(jQuery(this).attr("myattr") && jQuery(this).attr("myattr")!==""){
                jQuery(this).addClass("myattr-link").css("color", "red");
            }
        });
    });
```